# es6 join arrays of objects with different number of elements by id

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to join two arrays by id but with different amount of elements, Does any suggestions?

Thanks

Array 1

```
soccer = [{id: 1, name: 'Munich'}, {id: 2, name: 'Dortmund'}]
```

Array 2

```
points = [{id: 2, value: 40}]
```

Result

```
result = [{id: 1, name: 'Munich'}, {id: 2, name: 'Dortmund', value: 40}]
```

My attempt was

```
teams.map((item,i)=>{
    if(item.id === points[i].id){
      return Object.assign({},item, points[i])
    }
})
```

[image]

Comment: is there any case that the array 2 will contain 1 item with id:3? And do you want that to be in result array?

Comment: You can copy and paste from the console, you know. No need to use images, which are unreadable by screen readers and search engines...

Comment: `teams` in your attempt should be `soccer`? If so then there are more elements in `soccer`/`team` as in `points` but you try to access the elements in `points` with the index of `teams`/`soccer`

Comment: Your `.map()` should always return an element. Right now you would only return the matching object/team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should works:

```
soccer.map(item => ({...item, ...points.find(({id}) => id === item.id)}))
```

It basically [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the `soccer` array with both the props of the items in `soccer` and `points` array, using the `id` as key. Notice that given the order, if there are namesake props in both arrays, the `points` one wins (since it's the latter to be added).

Comment: There are many, many duplicates of this question on Stack Overflow...